# After merging a Mandrill account into Mailchimp, how can I accept a verification email if my sending domain is not setup to receive emails?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

We've been using Mandrill for years to deploy our app's signup confirmation and password reset emails. This has worked perfectly as we've had SPF and DKIM records added to the DNS configuration according to Mandrill's documentation for verifying sending domains.

However, after merging the Mandrill account with a new Mailchimp account--which is mandated by April 27th--it's requiring me to send a verification email to an address at that domain. The problem is that we don't have a mail server set up to receive emails. The domain is only used to send the "noreply@domain.com" emails.

Any ideas on how I might resolve this? Mailchimp is not giving an option to undo the merge, so effectively I have an app that users are not able to sign up for at the moment, which is problematic to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to configure at least one mailbox on that domain somehow to receive mail. That's the only way to confirm ownership of the domain.